# What is $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ for an abelian group $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I know that $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ is a  group for abelian groups $A$ and $B$.

> Is there some general statement about $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ and can $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A)$ be seen as a subgroup of $A$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z,A) \cong A$ canonically. Moreover, $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A)$ is also canonically isomorphic to element of order $n$ in $A$ : more precisely, the set $T_n(A) := \{x \in A : nx = 0\}$ is a subgroup of $A$, and again we have an isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A) \cong T_n(A)$. So the answer to your question is "yes".

Let's see why $1)$ is true  : we have a injection $A \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb Z,A)$, $a \to \phi_a : \phi_a(1) = a$ (recall that a morphism $\phi : \mathbb Z \to A$ is uniquely determined by the image of $1$). By any morphism $\psi$ is on the form $\psi = \phi_{\psi(1)}$ by definition, i.e the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: So we are working with $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and not with $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$?

Comment: Dear user372565, could me remind me the inverse of $2$ in $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$ ?

Comment: It is far from clear to me what you mean by your statement about $\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z},A)$.

Comment: ... just ignore my comment :D Thanks for your help!

Comment: If $A$ is abelian, element of order $n$ form a subgroup $T_n(A)$ (no idea of the official notation) and $T_n(A) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,A)$. I agree this was not very clear.

Comment: @user372565 : sure you're welcome ! I edited a bit my answer for make it more clear.

Comment: @user372565 : if you are satisfied with the answer, you can activate the little green mark so the answer is accepted and people know they do not need to answer you.

Answer (score 2):

1. $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)$$
   This is the group of homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, it is completely determined by the value $\phi(1)$. We can let $\phi(1)=a$, for $a\in A$, and every such element yields a homomorphism. Thus $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)\cong A$
2. $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A)$$
   Again $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$. So let $\phi(1)=a$. Notice that $0=\phi(n)=n\phi(1)=na$. We can therefore choose any $a\in A$ such that the order of $a$ divides $n$. Letting $N=\{a\in A\mid na=0\}$, we have that $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A)\cong N$

It is true that $N\subseteq A$ is a subgroup of $A$.

- If $a,b\in N$ then $na+nb=n(a+b)=0$ so $a+b\in N$.
- Associativity holds (since $A$ is a group)
- The identity element $0\in N$, since $n0=0$
- Every element has an additive inverse, since if $a\in N\iff an=0\iff (-a)n=0$

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

The category of abelian groups carries the structure of a monoidal category with the monoidal product being the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$. The monoidal unit of this monoidal product is $\mathbb{Z}$ (up to unique isomorphism).

Now, let $A$ and $X$ be two abelian groups.
We then have the following natural isomorphisms:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(X, A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(X\otimes \mathbb{Z}, A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(X,\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z},A)).$$ In the first step, we have used that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the monoidal unit. The second step employs the [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction).
By the [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) the Yoneda embedding is fully faithful and thus reflects isomorphisms. Consequently, the abelian groups $A$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ are isomorphic.

The above proof works for any (unital, associative) ring $R$ and its category of $R$-modules, not only the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. It does not, however, work for an arbitrary closed monoidal category. In an arbitrary closed monoidal category with monoidal unit $I$ the internal hom $[I,A]$ and the external hom $\operatorname{Hom}(I,A)$ are not necessarily isomorphic. For instance, think of the cartesian closed catgory of $G$-sets for a given non-trivial group $G$. See Jakob Werner's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338599/are-there-categories-whose-internal-hom-is-somewhat-exotic) for details.

---

By the universal property of the quotient group, precomposing with the canonical projection map $\pi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}$ gives and isomorphism of groups $$\pi_\ast :\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}},A)\xrightarrow{\sim}\{f\in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z},A) \ \vert \ n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \operatorname{ker}f\}.$$

Composing this isomophism with the inclusion into $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z},A)\cong A$ realizes $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}},A)$ as a subgroup of $A$.